# jQuery MouseOut active area is wrong and not working properly

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseout

I have created a div appears when I hover the cursor over a menu item with the class 'megamenu'. My jQuery adds a class 'open' to the div which changes the height value from 0 to 170px.

```
$(".megamenu").hover(
    function () {
        $(".about-us-megamenu").addClass("open");
    }
);
$(".about-us-megamenu").mouseout(
    function () {
        $(".about-us-megamenu").removeClass("open");
    }
);
```

This works fine but...

I want it to remove the class 'open' when the cursor moves out of the div. However, at present it only works within the width of the content wrapper I have on the page (960px) and removes the class after moving the cursor about 40px down, not 170px. My development URL is:

http://allentullett.co.uk/sandbox/guac/

Can anyone help me with my predicament?

Comment: where is the name of your script in your page? ( where is your Jquery code for the "mouseout" function)

Comment: I put it in the footer but not sure what you mean for the jquery code for the mouseout function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also have a mouseout handler on the div itself?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst exploring 'mouesout' more I came across the answer which worked for me wihch was 'mouseleave'

```
$(".megamenu").hover(
    function () {
        $(".about-us-megamenu").addClass("open");
    }
);
$(".about-us-megamenu").mouseleave(
    function () {
        $(".about-us-megamenu").removeClass("open");
    }
);
```

Works perfectly now.

Thank you both for your help though, greatly appreciated.